# Question about singletons and invoked methods

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've created a singleton to perform some server requests. However for some requests I need to get the results back. What's the best way to get them from the invoking classes (using the singleton) ?

This is the invoked method by the singleton when the data are received. Should I pass a target and selector to the singleton to perform a method of the invoker class ?

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // do something with the data
    //invoking passed selector here ?

    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing local notification inside the delegate would be better than receiving the selector of the invoker class. That local notification can handle by anyone who registers it and thus minimize the dependency.

Comment: What you mean is that the invoking classes should observe the singleton for notifications ?

Comment: yes. Before calling the singleton, it will register itself as an observer using "addObserver" and then it will handle the notifications to be send by the singleton.